# Use integration by parts to prove $ \int^\infty_0 x^ne^{-x} dx=n!$

Tags: improper-integrals, integration-by-parts

$ \int^\infty_0 (x^n)(e^{-x})  dx  $ and show that it is equal to $(n!)$ ? 
I know that if you differentiate $x^n$  infinitely you get $n!$ but I don't know how to prove?

Comment: Look at [the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: You prove this with integration by parts and induction.  The proof is probably somewhere in the wiki page but that's a lot of information in there.

Comment: Do you know what "integration by parts" mean?

Answer (score 1):

1. Show by parts that if $I_m = \int_0^{\infty} x^m e^{-x} \mathrm{d}x$, then $$I_m = m I_{m-1}$$
2. Show that $I_0 = 1$.
3. Conclude inductively that $I_n = n!$ for all $n$.

Comment: Sorry I still don't get it?Can someone show a step by step working?

Comment: What don't you get? Do you not understand, or are you unable to perform the proof?

Comment: I am unable to proof

Comment: Have you tried? If so, what have you tried?